git push is not finishing
I am working on a project that is starting to create issues with git.
I am using gitlab to host the repository.
I am working with the same "method" on other projects, but sometimes the "push" does not finish and no data is updated on the remote repository.

I edit my date
I add all changed files: git add *
I write my commit: git commit -m "blabla..."
I push: git push

sometimes git push does not finish, see the screenshot below. I can wait hours, but its not finishing. I have to cancel the progress and do a hard reset to my local files and copy them back to the directory and try again. then it works.
My questions:
How can I find out what the problem is?
How con I fix it?
(What information can I collect to help you guys/girls helping my troubleshoot it)
Thanks

edit:
If I do
git push --verbose i get a similar result:

upload/push does not finish.

Hello, what is the output of git log after your push command ?

And what is the git version you are using ? check with this command : git --version
And what OS are you using too ? MacOS / Windows / Linux ?
You can try using this command for push to see where the push is stuck : git push --verbose

@Buisson
git log states the following:
commit 8bb0f03c440bb87f86180b3747acb889afb5e44c (HEAD -> main)   Author: hugepanic <hugepanic@gmail.com>   Date:   Wed Oct 16 07:48:30 2024 +0200       more flaps and updated POH

git version 2.39.5
OS is linux/Debian

Please do not post pictures of text. Text is text! Copy it and paste it into your question as text (and format it).

Try uninstall git and reinstall it. The latest current version of git is the version 2.47.0
Here is how you can reinstall git :
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install git

After that you can try again to push.
One more possible reason your git push hangs is that you are trying to push a very large file.
I see you are pushing some blend files. Check if the size of the file is not too big, if the size of the file is very large you can increase the Git post buffer size to fix this issue.
Here is how you can increase it locally:
git config --local http.postBuffer 524288000

or globally:
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

Another issue with the Garbage collector you can try to run that command :
git gc

And try again to push

2.47.0 is buggy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79078235/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/79094424/7976758

reinstalling git resulted in the same git version --> 2.39.5
same result. it's not finishing.
I also suspecct that its not the git that is faulty. As said, only "sometimes" it does not push.

have you try to sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade before ?

I've update my answer if you can try my others solutions

I have done the "apt-get update and upgrade" routine and then purged and installed git again.  ---> did not change angything
also tried a reboot....   just to have it done... same result

git config --local http.postBuffer 524288000  ---> problem Solved!!!

Happy to hear that !

Issue is solved now!
the git post buffer seemed to be not sufficient!
git config --local http.postBuffer 524288000 solved the problem!!!
The blend file is not "that" big, about 38 MB, but obviously too much.
Thank you all for your help!
